# spdep::localmoran How to access classified cluster values?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, spdep

I am trying to get a LISA cluster map similar to this [one](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-can-i-create-a-lisa-cluster-map-in-r/108116/7), eg showing the  'High-high', 'Low-Low'..  cllassified values.

[image]

But, I can't figure out how to extract this classifications from the `localmoran()` output?

Here is an example:

```
data(afcon, package="spData")
oid <- order(afcon$id)
resI <- localmoran(afcon$totcon, nb2listw(paper.nb))
```

The `str(resI)` looks like this:

```
 'localmoran' num [1:42, 1:5] 0.00539 -0.01004 -0.09696 0.80382 6.94673 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:42] "TS" "AG" "MO" "LY" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "Ii" "E.Ii" "Var.Ii" "Z.Ii" ...
 - attr(*, "call")= language localmoran(x = afcon$totcon, listw = nb2listw(paper.nb))
 - attr(*, "quadr")='data.frame':   42 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ mean  : Factor w/ 4 levels "Low-Low","High-Low",..: 4 2 2 4 4 1 1 1 3 4 ...
  ..$ median: Factor w/ 4 levels "Low-Low","High-Low",..: 4 2 2 4 4 1 1 1 3 4 ...
  ..$ pysal : Factor w/ 4 levels "Low-Low","High-Low",..: 4 2 2 4 4 1 1 1 3 4 ...
```

I can easily access each colum (ie. Morans_I) values from the firt attribute, eg. `lisa_res_15[,1]` for `Ii`.

**But how to get the `mean` variable from the  `'quadr = 'data.frame'` object?**

I would like to use the values within `ggplot2` for an output.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449565/is-there-an-easier-way-to-access-attributes-of-a-class-in-r-can-i-use-dot-notat) after correcting my googling:

To access indivudual attributes of an object, one can use `attributes(x)$attributeName` or `attr(x, attributeName)`.

So, in my case, to access the 'mean' column from the data.frame `quadr` I can do:

```
attributes(resI)$quadr$mean
```

Returning:

```
attributes(resI)$quadr$mean
 [1] High-High High-Low  High-Low  High-High High-High Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-High 
[10] High-High High-High Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low  
[19] High-High Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-High  Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   High-High High-High
[28] High-High Low-Low   Low-Low   High-High Low-High  Low-High  High-High High-High Low-High 
[37] Low-Low   Low-Low   Low-Low   High-Low  Low-Low   Low-High 
Levels: Low-Low High-Low Low-High High-High
```